# Logical error in finding the prime number between two numbers

Tags: c++, computer-science, primes, number-theory

I am writing code to print prime numbers between two numbers but my code is giving the wrong output and freezing after giving it

http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;   
int main()
 {
 int t,j,i=0;
 cin>>t;
 int m,n;
 int primes[i];
 while(t--)  //t is the number of test-cases
  {
  cin>>m >>n;   //m and n are the numbers between which prime numbers have to be calculated
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++) //Using Sieve algorithm
      primes[i]=1;
    primes[0]=0;
    primes[1]=0;
    for(i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)
    {
        if(primes[i]==1)
        {
            for(j=2;i*j<=n;j++)
            primes[i*j]=0;
        }
    }
   for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
   {
       if(i>=m&&primes[i]==1)//Printing numbers which are greater than m
        cout<<i<<"\n";
   }
   cout<<"\n";
  }
```

Comment: You should post a complete program. Too often the problem is in the code not posted.

Comment: Note it would be more performant to create the sieve only once, and not a each time. (that requires to save `m`s and `n`s in an *array*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int primes[i];`

is not legal C++. And since `i == 0` it's not even working C++.

Clearly you need to *allocate* an array big enough.

```
int *primes;
while(t--)  //t is the number of test-cases
  {
  cin>>m >>n;   //m and n are the numbers between which prime numbers have to be calculated
  primes = new int[n+1]; // allocate a big enough array
  ...
  delete[] primes;
}
```

Comment: If the static array is big enough it will work. How can you be sure a static array is big enough? I should add I haven't tested your code, so it might not work even with a static array,

Comment: Modified it but now runtime error is coming on SPOJ

Comment: The web site says n <= 1000000000. A static array won't work with n that big, nor will my method. I think you need a more sophisticated algorithm.

Comment: In fact reading the web site again it says 'Warning: large Input/Output data, be careful with certain languages (though most should be OK if the algorithm is well designed)'. As I said you need a better algorithm.

Comment: Well I modified my code using segmented sieve but it is still giving runtime error on SPOJ.

Comment: <blink>          int t,j,i=0;
        cin>>t;
        int m,n;
        int primes[10000];
        while(t--)
         {
         cin>>m >>n;
         for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
          primes[i]=1;
         primes[0]=0;
         primes[1]=0;
         for(i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)
          {
            if(primes[i]==1)
            {
                for(j=2;i*j<=n;j++)
                primes[i*j]=0;
            }
          }
          for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
           {
           if(i>=m&&primes[i]==1)
            cout<<i<<"\n";
          }
          cout<<"\n";
          }

         return 0;
       }</blink>